# How do Styled Components forward props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, styled-components

I have been working with Styled Components for a while now but I'll be honest I never really understood how it works. That is what my question is about.

So, I understand styled components can adapt based on props. What I don't understand is how does the forwarding of props work.

For Example in my case, Im working with React Native. There are some default props which I have given to my input field. Now, styled component wrapper automatically picks up the default height prop but If I explicitly pass the prop it does not pick it up and I have to manually get it from props. What is that about?

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components/native";

const StyledTextInput = styled.TextInput`
   /* Why do I have to do this for custom heights.
    * Isn't height automatically get forwarded?
    */

  /* if I comment this height style out, It takes defaultProp height but doesn't take custom height
   * I have to uncomment it for the custom height
   */

  height: ${({ height }) => height};

   ...other styles
`;

const TextInput = ({ height }) => {
  return <StyledTextInput height={height} />;
};

TextInput.defaultProps = {
  height: 50
};

export default TextInput;


// Then In some Smart Component
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.app}>
        <TextInput height={200} /> // ???
        ...other stuff
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Here are my Questions:

- What are the cases in which styled component automatically picks up the prop?
- Which props are automatically forwarded.
- How does this prop forwarding work?

Documentation doesn't talk much about that or maybe I have missed it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

All standard attributes are automatically forwarded props. Standard attributes like `defaultValue` and `type`. Take note of the camel case notation for attributes in React.

If it's a custom attribute like `someCustomAttribute` prop, it's not passed directly to DOM.

If there are props that are **true to all instances** of the styled component, you can make use of [`.attrs`](https://styled-components.com/docs/faqs#when-to-use-attrs).

```
const StyledTextInput = styled.TextInput.attrs(props => ({
  height: props.height
}))`
  // other styles
`
```